# I want to get inner tag value for the md-autocomplete but I am not able to get text valu , Find code below

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angular-material

HTML:

```
<md-virtual-repeat-container role="presentation" ng-class="{ 'md-not-found': $mdAutocompleteCtrl.notFoundVisible() }" class="md-autocomplete-suggestions-container md-whiteframe-z1 md-virtual-repeat-container md-orient-vertical ng-hide" ng-hide="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.hidden" ng-mouseup="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.mouseUp()" ng-mouseleave="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.listLeave()" ng-mouseenter="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.listEnter()" md-auto-shrink-min="1" md-auto-shrink="" aria-hidden="true" style="left: 676.483px; min-width: 270.717px; max-width: 941.2px; top: auto; bottom: -147.917px; max-height: 240px; height: 96px;">
<div class="md-virtual-repeat-scroller">
    <div class="md-virtual-repeat-sizer" style="height: 96px;"></div>
    <div class="md-virtual-repeat-offsetter">
        <ul id="ul-3" ng-class="::menuClass" class="md-autocomplete-suggestions">
            <!-- mdVirtualRepeat: item in $mdAutocompleteCtrl.matches -->
            <li md-extra-name="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.itemName" ng-click="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.select($index)" ng-class="{ selected: $index === $mdAutocompleteCtrl.index }" md-virtual-repeat="item in $mdAutocompleteCtrl.matches" class="ng-scope" role="button" tabindex="0">
                <!-- mdAutocompleteParentScope: -->
                <md-autocomplete-parent-scope md-autocomplete-replace="" class="ng-scope">
                    <span md-highlight-text="searchText1" id="pincodeCity"><span class="highlight">110081</span>,Delhi</span>
                </md-autocomplete-parent-scope>
            </li>
            <li md-extra-name="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.itemName" ng-click="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.select($index)" ng-class="{ selected: $index === $mdAutocompleteCtrl.index }" md-virtual-repeat="item in $mdAutocompleteCtrl.matches" class="ng-scope" role="button" tabindex="0">
                <!-- mdAutocompleteParentScope: -->
                <md-autocomplete-parent-scope md-autocomplete-replace="" class="ng-scope">
                    <span md-highlight-text="searchText1" id="pincodeCity"><span class="highlight">110081</span>,Nizampur</span>
                </md-autocomplete-parent-scope>
            </li>
            <!-- ngIf: $mdAutocompleteCtrl.notFoundVisible() -->            
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Protractor code:

```
let foo = $$('.md-autocomplete-suggestions').$$('.highlight');
    expect(foo.getText()).toEqual([',Delhi', ',Nizampur']);
```

I have tried with above code, but it didn't work.

Is there any way I can find/Select text field in a span tag.

Comment: You want html inside md-autocomplete

Comment: yes, I want to select value under span tag value ",Nizampur"

Answer (score 1):

Ok you have to put id at the span

es:

```
 <span id="Spansearch" md-highlight-text="searchText1"><span class="highlight">110081</span>,Delhi</span>
```

after whit this you can get all html with this

```
$( "#Spansearch" ).html();
```

if you wont tu get only `Nizampur`

you can use this

```
$( "#Spansearch" ).html().split(",")[1];
```

Comment: while executing the above code the following error is populating.      
        Error:Failed: $(...).getText(...).split is not a function

Comment: i have tried with $(foo).text() but did'nt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Protractor, `getText()` returns a promise that you need to resolve. So when you're using your `expect`, you need to do that post you've resolved the promise.

I suppose you can do something like

```
     let foo = $$('.md-autocomplete-suggestions').$$('.highlight>span[1]');
      foo.getText().then(function(text){
       expect(text).toEqual('Delhi');

       })
```

Comment: i got the output like  "Expected [ '110081', '110081' ] to equal 'Delhi'."  but i need Delhi to be Expected.

Comment: You need to select the second span instead of the first.